# Microsoft Graph API on existing MVC application

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure-web-app-service, asp.net-webhooks

I am implementing a webhook using a Microsoft Graph API using the tutorial on https://github.com/microsoftgraph/aspnet-webhooks-rest-sample.

I have made a demo version to work on my localhost. I have an existing web application host on Mircosoft Azure.

The issue or rather concern is that do I use the Account Controller provided by the link https://github.com/microsoftgraph/aspnet-webhooks-rest-sample. Or Merge it with my existing application

Comment: Do you mean merge Microsoft Graph API to your existing MVC application? If so, I think you need to merge the account controller too. If any detailed issues. Please give more detailed information.

Answer (score 0):

I have merged it but having trouble with the login process. The existing login is troubling with the login using office365. note that the office365 users are not part of the users table yet